# How to get a new data in an existing repository of git and commit to svn?

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

I am using git-svn to get a data in svn repo from git. I successfully did import data from git to svn with submodules (I converted submodules as sub-tree of git) using some around work, and it worked fine.

But now I am getting stuck. If I want get a git pull a update data of existing repos of git, it gives me all updated data on my local branch, but I am not able to dcommit to svn using git svn dcommit command it gives me error message as follows:

```
Unable to determine upstream SVN information from HEAD history 
Perhaps the repository is empty. at /usr/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 521.
```

Any instructions on how to do this would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I may be mistaken but my understanding is that git-svn cannot be shared with an upstream git repo only a subversion one.

I totally hosed my git trying to do what you are trying to do, pull from a remote git repo then push to a subversion one.

What I now do is use git to do my SCC, and I copy files into a subversion only controlled local tree and then check that into subversion.

I wrote a ruby script which does the sync between the local git working tree and the local subversion one. It only copies changed files and only the files I care about. Then I do a normal `svn ci` from the subversion working tree.

Ok I found the source of my understanding here... http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn under the heading CAVEATS...

> For the sake of simplicity and
>   interoperating with a less-capable
>   system (SVN), it is recommended that
>   all git svn users clone, fetch and
>   dcommit directly from the SVN server,
>   and avoid all git
>   clone/pull/merge/push operations
>   between git repositories and branches.
>   The recommended method of exchanging
>   code between git branches and users is
>   git format-patch and git am, or just
>   'dcommit’ing to the SVN repository.
>
> Running git merge or git pull is NOT
>   recommended on a branch you plan to
>   dcommit from. Subversion does not
>   represent merges in any reasonable or
>   useful fashion; so users using
>   Subversion cannot see any merges
>   you’ve made. Furthermore, if you merge
>   or pull from a git branch that is a
>   mirror of an SVN branch, dcommit may
>   commit to the wrong branch.